# Google maps button replace

Tags: javascript, css, button, maps

I'd like to replace the default google maps interface.
It is not a big deal, i just want to replace the buttons in the top (Map, Satellite, Hibryd, Terrain)

So in the 1st step i have to hide the originals. How can i do this in V3? 
(i can hide them with css, but its not an elegant method :)

I can put 3 buttons with z-index:9999 to the top of the maps. How can I make them work such as the original ones?

Thanks for the help. R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the mapTypeControl - there's an example of how to disable default controls at
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map

That same page contains instructions for creating your own custom controls as well.